# Creating responsive grid layout in android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-gridlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#804fc4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:rowCount="5">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>


    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm trying to create a `grid layout` that can fit in most of the devices. But children on right side are getting less `margin` compared to the children on left side. I've tried using `gravity` attribute but it didn't work. How can I give each side same amount of margin?

Here is the pic of how it looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCLut.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning specific widths to the buttons when they should be allowed to vary. Try the following using

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

as XML attributes for the buttons. Also, make the width of the *GridLayout* `match_parent`.

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#804fc4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:rowCount="5">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text="button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```